# Change one value of column based on value of another column in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two arrays in matlab (small part shown below):

```
    A     B
   2     3
   0,1   3,6
   0,1   3,6
   0,1   3,6
   0,1   3,2
   0     3,2
   0     3,2
   0     3,2
   0     2,4
   0     4,3
   0,1   4,3
   0,1   4,3
   0,1   4,3
   0,1   4,3
   0,1   4,3
```

What I want to do: If value in column A is zero, value in column B should be changed to zero or NaN.

I would appreciate any help regarding this!
I am new to matlab and I am not sure if a 'for - end' loop can/should be used?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [*logical indexing*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
B(A == 0) = 0;
```

The expression `A == 0` returns a logical array (of booleans), containing "1"s at the positions that correspond to the zero elements in `A`. Feeding this boolean array into `B`, selects only the elements from `B` at the locations of the "1"s. The zero assignment is self-explanatory.

However, when `A` contains decimal values, Rody correctly pointed out that the comparison operation might be inaccurate and return false results. Therefore you should set a tolerance (*e.g* a multiple of [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)), like so:

```
tol = eps;           %// Tolerance
B(abs(A) < tol) = 0;
```

If you don't care for floating point inaccuracy, and `A` niether contains `NaN` values nor complex numbers, you can use the following shortened syntax:

```
B(~A) = 0;
```

Comment: +1. Few caveats though; second notation does not work when `A` contains `NaN` or complex numbers. First one is directly comparing floating point double precision number to `0`, which can be tricky when not using `eps` or some other tolerance

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Kudos for your sharpness :) I've amended my answer.

Comment: I don't have any NaN or complex values in 'A'. Thank you so much for all your help! :)